# Giving a variable name as a function input and obtaining its value as an output

Tags: matlab, function

I have lots of variables in the workspace in MATLAB and I have to create some statistics through a function. I need to enter the name of the variable as a function input and I need to return its value in the function and then process it.

```
varName='Sa'
function [ someStatistics ] = AnalyzeThis (varName);
```

So, in this `AnalyzeThis` function, I need to obtain the value of `Sa` (which is a one-dimensional array). How can I do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Short answer:** use [`evalin`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/evalin.html):

```
function someStatistics = AnalyzeThis(varName)
  varValue = evalin('caller', varName);
  % Do stuff with varValue
  ....
end
```

**Longer answer:** you shouldn't really be designing your code to depend on functions like `evalin` ([such as "evil" `eval`](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/56124-eval-is-evil-using-variables-created-dynamically-info-retrieval)). Instead of having a whole bunch of variables with different names in your calling workspace, store the data in [structures](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/structures.html), which can be easily [accessed by field names](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/generate-field-names-from-variables.html).